# Azure Service Bus errors out when trying to send 100 MB batch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azureservicebus

I am trying to do a PoC to test the latest feature by the Azure Service Bus Premium that can handle messages of size 100 MB. I tried to do it in two modes.

1. Send 3495253 count of messages in a batch with the cumulative message sizeInBytes    104857595. THis is definitely less than the 100 MB limit. When I do this, I get the following error,
   System.InvalidOperationException: 'The link 'G5S2:196:amqps://sbpocbatching1.servicebus.windows.net/-c53a3e1c;0:5:6' is force detached by the broker because publisher(link82) received a batch message with no data in it. Detach origin: Publisher.'
2. If I try to send one message of size 100MB in that batch, it times out after 1 minute.

Is this a problem on my side or the Azure? I have a very good internet connection that shows   350 Mbps download and 300 Mbps upload.

Can anyone throw some light on what am I missing here?

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

// connection string to your Service Bus namespace
string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://sbpocbatching1.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=czthvMkrDa6W34KrpfOHttKpEnuv90oWfAh6Z9tBpCM=";

// name of your Service Bus topic
string topicName = "mytopic";

// the client that owns the connection and can be used to create senders and receivers
ServiceBusClient client;

// the sender used to publish messages to the topic
ServiceBusSender sender;

// number of messages to be sent to the topic
int numOfMessages = 0;

//byte[] data = new byte[100 * 1024 * 1024];
//Random rng = new Random();
//rng.NextBytes(data);
string strdata = GenerateString();
{
    // The Service Bus client types are safe to cache and use as a singleton for the lifetime
    // of the application, which is best practice when messages are being published or read
    // regularly.
    //
    // Create the clients that we'll use for sending and processing messages.
    client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
    sender = client.CreateSender(topicName);


    // create a batch 
    using ServiceBusMessageBatch messageBatch = await sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();
    //messageBatch.TryAddMessage(new ServiceBusMessage(strdata));
    for (numOfMessages = 0; numOfMessages <= 104857600; numOfMessages++)
    {
        //if (messageBatch.SizeInBytes >= messageBatch.MaxSizeInBytes / 4)
        //    break;
        // try adding a message to the batch
        if (!messageBatch.TryAddMessage(new ServiceBusMessage(strdata)))
        {
            // if it is too large for the batch
            //throw new Exception($"The message {i} is too large to fit in the batch.");
            break;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        // Use the producer client to send the batch of messages to the Service Bus topic
        await sender.SendMessagesAsync(messageBatch);
        Console.WriteLine($"A batch of {numOfMessages} messages has been published to the topic.");
    }
    finally
    {
        // Calling DisposeAsync on client types is required to ensure that network
        // resources and other unmanaged objects are properly cleaned up.
        await sender.DisposeAsync();
        await client.DisposeAsync();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end the application");
    Console.ReadKey();

    GenerateString();

}

String GenerateString()
{
    int length = 1;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append("A");
    }

    return sb.ToString();

}
```

Comment: While the total size is under 100MB, a batch of 3,495,253 messages sounds like a problematic point to look into.

Comment: @SeanFeldman: Thank you for your response. There are no documented instances of having a large message count in a batch. Else, Microsoft should tell us what is the acceptable count inside a batch. Also, as you indicated, my second option to send all the 100 MB in one message also never goes through. My internet speed is pretty good at 300 Mbps up and down.

Comment: There is a limit on the number of messages in the batch which the documentation does not highlight well at the moment - but which the content authors are working to address.  The SDK is unable to validate this upfront, as the limit is not currently exposed outside of the service.  More context can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/21451

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this issue is (besides the straight forward solutions of narrowing the batches or enlarging the Max Message Size), if you are using a premium Service-Bus, to create a proper Scale Out condition.

I faced the same problem and noticed that my Scale Out (and In) condition, was only triggered for the CPU parameter. That caused an excessive use of memory without scaling out.
Once I added Scale Out by memory usage condition - It solved the problem.